# set admin bar to visible for authors, contributors, moderators and admins

Tags: admin-bar

Is there any way that I can set the Toolbar visible to authors, editors and admins and off to everyone else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the [capability](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capabilities) of the users you can determine whether to show or not the [admin bar](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/show_admin_bar).

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_admin_bar' );

function remove_admin_bar() {
    if( ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) || ! current_user_can( 'editor' ) || ! current_user_can( 'author' ) ) {
        show_admin_bar(false);
    }
}
```